# Proposition from the book "Convex analysis and measurable multifunction "

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, definition

[image]

Please , what is $F_{\sigma}$?
And all $U$ can be writen as $\cup F_n$, or only open set ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An [$F_\sigma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set) set is a set which is the countable union of closed sets.  Every open set in a metric space can be written as such, but not every set is $F_\sigma$.

To see that the sets $F_n$ if the proof are closed, consider their compliment:

$$
F_n^c=\{x\in X\vert d(x,X-U)<\frac{1}{n}\}
$$ These sets are open, since if $y\in F_n^c$, $d(y,X-U)<1/n$ and the same inequality will hold for all $x$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood about $y$.

Comment: Ok, so $U$ must be open !, please how to show that $F_n$ is closed ? if i take $(u_k)\subset X$,such that $u_k \rightarrow u$ from $d(u_k,X-U)\geq \frac1n$ how to fined that $d(u,X-U)\geq \frac1n $ please